# DockerでLet's Encryptを利用してSSL化したら「simp_le:1446」エラーが発生する

Tags: nginx, docker, docker-compose, letsencrypt

***事象***
現在Dockerを利用してWebサイトをSSL化しようと画策しております。
そこで、Docker-composeにLet's Encryptを追加して対応しようとしておりますが、
表題のエラーが発生し、うまくSSL化できない状態です。
以下に詳細を記載します。

環境
Conoha VPS
CentOS 7
Docker
mysql:5.7.21
エラー

> ERROR:simp_le:1446: CA marked some of the authorizations as invalid,
>   which likely means it could not access
>   http://example.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/X. Did you set correct
>   path in -d example.com:path or --default_root? Are all your domains
>   accessible from the internet? Please check your domains' DNS entries,
>   your host's network/firewall setup and your webserver config. If a
>   domain's DNS entry has both A and AAAA fields set up, some CAs such as
>   Let's Encrypt will perform the challenge validation over IPv6. If your
>   DNS provider does not answer correctly to CAA records request, Let's
>   Encrypt won't issue a certificate for your domain (see
>   https://letsencrypt.org/docs/caa/). Failing authorizations:
>   https://acme-v01.api.letsencrypt.org/acme/authz/pQw__WwGNMFP2gfsW76-lKGQCWR_7QmKk_6qOC1k2xU

***Docker-compose（一部伏字）***

```
version: '2'
services:
  db:
    container_name: mysql
    image: mysql:5.7.21
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    volumes:
      - /home/web/mysql:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
    restart: always
    networks:
      - net-proxy

  wordpress1:
    container_name: wp_1
    depends_on:
      - db
    image: wordpress
    volumes:
      - /home/web/wordpress/wp_1/wp-content:/var/www/html/wp-content
    external_links:
      - db
    expose:
      - 80
    environment:
      VIRTUAL_HOST: 【domain名】
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: password
      LETSENCRYPT_HOST: 【domain名】
      LETSENCRYPT_EMAIL: 【*******】@gmail.com # Lets Encrypt
    restart: always
    networks:
      - net-proxy

  letsencrypt-nginx-proxy-companion:
    image: jrcs/letsencrypt-nginx-proxy-companion
    volumes:
      - /home/web/certs:/etc/nginx/certs:rw
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro
    volumes_from:
      - nginx-proxy
    restart: always
    networks:
      - net-proxy

  nginx-proxy:
    container_name: nginx_proxy
    image: jwilder/nginx-proxy
    privileged: true
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
    volumes:
      - /etc/nginx/vhost.d
      - /usr/share/nginx/html
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro
      - /home/web/certs:/etc/nginx/certs:ro
    restart: always
    networks:
      - net-proxy
    environment:
      DEFAULT_HOST: 【ドメイン名】

networks:
  net-proxy:
    external: true
```

上記以外にもOS側で制御する必要がある設定などあればご教示いただきたく思います。
ちなみに、現状HTTP://【ドメイン名】であれば正常に接続することができています。

以上、よろしくお願いします。

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/176169

Comment: いろいろお話を聞かせてください。このエラーはどの時点ででるエラーですか？certbotを動かした際のエラーでしょうか。

Comment: ご質問ありがとうございます。はい。certbot(Let's Encrypt)を実行した際に発生したエラーです。以下に前後の表示されたメッセージを記載します。

letsencrypt | 759:INFO:simp_le:1479: Generating new certificate private key
letsencrypt |  Received event die for container 2241bbd8cfa3
nginx_proxy exited with code 0
質問のエラー
letsencrypt | Challenge validation has failed, see error log.
letsencrypt | 
letsencrypt | Debugging tips: -v improves output verbosity. Help is available under --help.
letsencrypt | /app
letsencrypt | Sleep for 3600s
letsencrypt | Received event start for container 2241bbd8cfa3

Comment: エラーにもありますように、nginx_proxyが止まってしまっているのは関係なさそうですか？`docker-compose up`もしくは`certbot`実行時のどちらの時点で止まっておりますか？`docker-compose up`時であれば、`tty:true`を`docker-compose.yml`に追記してあげて、nginx_proxyが生存している状態にしてみたらどうでしょう。

Comment: ご連絡が遅れて申し訳ありません。
tty:trueを設定してみましたが、同様のERROR:simp_le:1446エラーが発生しだめなようです。
一応nginxも可動しているように思えます。80番portでは正常に接続できるためです。
depends_on:
      - nginx-proxy
を設定してあげてnginxが起動してからletsencryptを起動するように設定してもやはり同じエラーが発生してしまいます。

Comment: nginxを起動する際に以下のようなエラーも発生していましたが、関係ありそうでしょうか。
nginx_proxy  | dockergen.1 | 2019/04/18 05:54:44 Contents of /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf did not change. Skipping notification 'nginx -s reload'

Comment: それは関係ないと思います…。そういえばですがcertbotを動かすときに、nginxを動かさないでやってみたらどうなりますか？certbotを実行するときに、letsencryptが80番ポートを使用するシーンがあった気がします(オプションによると思いますが)。現状、nginxで80番ポートを使っているので、いったんnginxを立ち上げないでletsencryptだけで動かしてみたらどうなりますか？

Comment: nginxを起動しない状態でletsencryptを可動させてみましたが、以下のエラーになってしまいます。。。
Error: can't get nginx-proxy container ID !
Check that you are doing one of the following :
- Use the --volumes-from option to mount volumes from the nginx-proxy container.
- Set the NGINX_PROXY_CONTAINER env var on the letsencrypt-companion container to the name of the nginx-proxy container.
- Label the nginx-proxy container to use with 'com.github.jrcs.letsencrypt_nginx_proxy_companion.nginx_proxy'.
web_letsencrypt-nginx-proxy-companion_1 exited with code 1

Comment: OS側はnetstat -ltupnで８０番も４４３番もListen状態であることも確認しました。firewall-cmd --list-portsでもどちらもtcpで開放されていました。

Comment: また、nmapで外部から８０番と４４３番にアクセスしてみると、どちらもopenになっていました。

Comment: エラーについて、nginx-proxyをコメントアウトした際に、docker-composeの起動時にletsencryptの'volumes_from:'も同時にコメントアウトしましたか？

Comment: はい。letsEncryptは別のDocker-composeファイルとして以下の通り記載しています。
version: '2'
services:
  letsencrypt-nginx-proxy-companion:
    image: jrcs/letsencrypt-nginx-proxy-companion
    volumes:
      - /home/web/certs:/etc/nginx/certs:rw
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro
    restart: always
    networks:
      - net-proxy

networks:
  net-proxy:
    external: true

また、dockerのプロセスもマウントしているファイルも全て削除してからリトライしています。

Comment: certbotをnginxのコンテナ内に直接インストールして試してみたところ、以下のようなエラーが発生しました。
コマンド→certbot certonly --webroot -w /usr/share/nginx/html -d www.<<ドメイン>> -m *******@gmail.com --agree-tos
Saving debug log to /var/log/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.log
Plugins selected: Authenticator webroot, Installer None
Obtaining a new certificate
Performing the following challenges:
http-01 challenge for www.<<ドメイン>>

To fix these errors, please make sure that your domain name was
   entered correctly and the DNS A/AAAA record(s) for that domain
   contain(s) the right IP address.

Comment: ConoHaVPSを利用していますが、設定はA/AAAAどちらも設定済みとなっており、nslookupでも正引き逆引きどちらも利用できる状態でした。

Comment: なんか私もそんなので、一度止まった記憶が、、なので、Ubuntuのコンテナを動かして、そこでcertbotを動かしています。
`certbot-auto certonly --standalone` で、やってます。

Comment: 原因が判明しました！原因はドメインのレコードの設定にありました。
私はwwwに対応させてはいましたが、通常(@)の設定をしていなかったことでLetsEncryptが見に行けなかったようでした。Docker-compose内にwww.と記載してもだめなようですね。初心者すぎるミスのようで申し訳ありません。。
ご助言ありがとうございました！

Answer (score 1):

原因はドメインのレコードの設定にありました。 私はwwwに対応させてはいましたが、通常(@)の設定をしていなかったことでLetsEncryptが見に行けなかったようでした。Docker-compose内にwww.と記載してもだめなようです。